# Rewriting URLs using pretty-config

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, prettyfaces

I am facing problem with rewriting urls using `pretty-config.xml` and I want help. This is what I want.

I want to render the URL as:

```
http://www.example.com/{productId}
```

and the page actual URL is:

```
http://www.example.com/page/product.jsf
```

In short, I have one page but I want to render it each time as different url based on product id from the backing bean.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds fairly simple. I would use this:

```
<url-mapping>
  <pattern value="/#{productId}" />
  <view-id value="/pages/product.jsf" />
</url-mapping>
```

Just make sure that you generate the correct links in your pages upon rendering.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Lincoln but here it is, #{myBackingBean.productId} but now it's showing /pages/product.jsf in the URL.

Comment: Not sure how that would happen. You mean the link is not being generated properly? You need to make sure that you pass all required parameters to your <h:link> component.

Comment: I am getting the page rendered after bean method, so how it should be?

Comment: You probably just need to set the value of `#{myBackingBean.productId} ` before you navigate. These docs explain:  http://ocpsoft.org/docs/prettyfaces/3.3.3/en-US/html_single/#config.actions.navigation

Comment: Not sure how else to help without looking at your project. Perhaps you could upload a sample maven project that reproduces this issue to our support forums on http://ocpsoft.org/support/ ?